# how to querying a document with a several criteria on mongoDB & NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hi im having a weird problem i have a query this query.

```
find({username: "user_1" ,  words: { $elemMatch: { "word": "RATIONAL", "subwords": "RAT" } }})
```

and this is the document structure :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGGLo.png

when i try this query on mongoDB shell it works perfectly but when i try it on NodeJS it returns me the document based only the username.
thanks everyone

Comment: Your schema might be wrong. Are you using `mongoose`?

Comment: actually you just solved the problem. thank you

Comment: The majority of cases where there is a difference between the mongoDB shell and the code query results, the reason is the schema.

Answer (score 0):

To find the matches try running this query:

`find({username: "user_1" , "words.word": "RATIONAL", "words.subwords": "RAT" })`